Загрузка файла с сервера. Telebot
Python. Telebot.
В боте сохраняю введённые пользователем данные в таблицу БД sqlite3. Далее конвертирую в .xlsx и сохраняю, например, в папку /data.
Не понимаю, как могу скачать этот файл через интерфейс бота. То есть, необходимо организовать скачивание через inline-кнопку. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

А в чем проблема то? Указываете путь, отправляете как документ‍♀️
bot.send_document()

Насколько я понимаю, bot.send_document() отправляет файл пользователя боту. А мне нужно, наоборот, скачать файл из папки /data себе на телефон. Папка /data находится на сервере хостинга. Либо я вас неверно понял.

bot.send_document() - отправляет документ от бота -> юзеру ‍♀️

Вот минимальный пример, показывающий как отправить файл пользователю:
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    kb = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Скачать файл', callback_data='download')
    kb.add(btn1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Нажми кнопку, чтобы скачать файл", reply_markup=kb)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: callback.data == "download")
def func_download(callback):
    file = open("твой_файл.xlsx", "rb")
    bot.send_document(callback.message.chat.id, file)


Лучше использовать конструкцию "with open", которая автоматически закроет файл, а то как-то не хорошо оставлять его открытым.
